# OSX - find out what starts a process

Tags: macos

I am trying to find out what starts the Autodesk service "AdSSO-v2", which starts together with AutoCAD on my Mac.

(I would like to deactivate it because it drains my battery with average CPU usage of 10% but it does not seem to be required to run the actual AutoCAD process)

I can find the process:

```
launchctl list |grep -i adsso
1102    0   com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x1000000e.AdSSO-v2
```

But I can't find any Autodesk or Adsso-v2 plist anywhere in

> ~/Library/LaunchAgents 
>   /Library/LaunchAgents
>   /Library/LaunchDaemons
>   /Library/StartupItems
>   /System/Library/LaunchAgents
>   /System/Library/LaunchDaemons

What else could I do to find what launches the process?

Any hint wold be appreciated. Maybe there is a way?

Greetings, Chris

Comment: Issue the following two commands:   `launchctl print gui/$UID | awk '/AdSSO-v2/ {print $1}'` then `sudo launchctl procinfo XXXX | grep uid` where XXX is the PID that the command just gave you.  This will give you the owner of the process and we can start from there....

Answer (score 1):

You could try **Activity Monitor** located in the *Utilities* folder.
Select `View > All Processes` then filter on `AdSSO-v2`. When you found it, select it then click the `Info` button (or ⌘-I). In the window that pops up select the third tab. (*Open files and ports*). You will see a list of files and where they are located. The culprit *may* be in that list.

If that doesn't work try selecting Autocad and do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Generally: Have you looked into the /Application package and/or (~)/Library/Application_Support folders?

As this is the single signon process, it may be required for some operations…

Anyway. It is sid to be located  directly under /Application Aupport/Autodesk

([Mac OS process AdSSO-v2](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/installation-licensing/mac-os-process-adsso-v2/td-p/6656455))

As I do not use this programme I can only guess: deleting that process might have unintended consequences. If you say the application works fine without it, why not just kill the process once the main application is launched?

Comment: <  If you say the application works fine without it, why not just kill the process once the main application is launched?

<--- Because it keeps coming back.